# How do you set Matlab y-axis to scientific notation without scale factor?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot a set of data but I want the y-axis to display in scientific notation without a scale factor. I've used "ax = gca; ax.YAxis.Exponent = 1;" however, this then incorporates a scale factor at the top of the y-axis. How do I plot in scientific notation without a scale factor? I've added an example photo just to help clarify what I mean. Code below. Thanks

```
close all; clear; clc;

v(1) = 0;
y(1) = 120;
g = 9.80665;
T = 5.044;
dt=10^-3;
t = 0:dt:T;
k = 0.5*1e-5*0.82*0.5;
m = 250;


for ii = 2:length(t)

    f= k*v(ii-1).^2 - m*g;
    v(ii) = v(ii-1) + (f/m)*dt;
    y(ii) = y(ii-1) + v(ii)*dt;
    
    if y(ii) < 0 && y(ii-1) > 0
        Timpact = t(ii);
    end
    
end

D=@(g,t) 120+(.5*-g).*(t.^2);
D1=D(g,t);
Net=m*g-k*v.^2;
F1=m*g;
F2=k*v.^2; 
F3=-F2+F1;
A=Net/m;
Quality=1-(A/g);
  
figure
 plot (t,Quality);
 title ('Relative Microgravity Quality')
 xlabel('Time [s]')
 ylabel('Relative Microgravity Quality')
 hold on 
 grid on
```

Example of what I want:

[image: figure]

ax = gca;
ax.YAxis.Exponent = 1;

The above converts the y-axis to scientific notation but then incorporates a scale factor of x10^1. If I set the exponent to 0, it eliminates the scale factor, but then is also not in scientific notation.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to edit the tick label format

```
ax = gca;
ax.YAxis.TickLabelFormat = '%.2e';
```

or equivalently using the `ytickformat` function:

```
ytickformat( '%.2e' );
```

See the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ytickformat.html#bvayhxa-1-fmt) for more details on the format strings, they are the same convention as other string-formatting functions like `fprintf`.

In this case, `%.2e` is 2 decimal places in exponential notation.

[image: figure]